# How to move right, left,top and bottom for zoom Image in android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-activity

I am uploading an image in a screen. There i have Zoom-in an Zoom-out buttons. Already I have done Zoom-in and Zoom-out functions. Its working fine. what I need is, I want to drag and see the Image completely. But what happens now is, the image is not moving. I have 4 butons here. LeftButton,RightButton,TopButton and BottomButton. If I click 'LeftButton', Image should move left side. Similarly all the other functions.  I am not really having idea, what I need to write inside the button clicks. Could anyone please guide me for this? Any help would be really appreciated..

Here is my code:

selectedPicture is my ImageLayout

```
case R.id.zoomInCtrl:
    float x = selectedPicture.getScaleX();
    float y = selectedPicture.getScaleY();

    selectedPicture.setScaleX((float) (x + 0.5));
    selectedPicture.setScaleY((float) (y + 0.5));

    return true;
case R.id.zoomOutCtrl:
    x = selectedPicture.getScaleX();
    y = selectedPicture.getScaleY();

    selectedPicture.setScaleX((float) (x - 0.5));
    selectedPicture.setScaleY((float) (y - 0.5));

    return true;
case R.id.leftCtrl:
    /* code for move left */
    return true;
case R.id.rightCtrl:
    /* code for move right */
    return true;
case R.id.topCtrl:
    /* code for move top */
    return true;
case R.id.bottomCtrl:
    /* code for move bottom */
    return true;
```

Comment: Check out : https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView

Comment: @HareshChhelana I am already try to used this TouchImageView but I could't get the longpress so I try to use this please check My code [link](https://github.com/Reegan01/AddViewOnTouchImageView/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/kenturf/myimagezoom/MainActivity.java)

Comment: @HareshChhelana I want to fit pin marks on the TouchImageView using onDraw.But I could't know how to create this so I try another way ..

Answer (score 0):

I think the setTranslationX and setTranslationY methods of View are the best fit for what you want.